# Is running new thread in Timer.5 boost::asio tutorial necessary?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

**Question 1**: Is starting a new thread in [Timer.5](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer5.html) boost::asio  tutorial really needed?

```
  ...
  boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_context::run, &io));
  io.run();
  t.join();
  ...
```

Tutorial says:

> As you already know, the asio library provides a guarantee that callback handlers will only be called from threads that are currently calling io_context::run().

But if I run this

```
  ...
  // boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_context::run, &io));
  io.run();
  // t.join();
  ...
```

... callbacks are still executed despite the fact that timers are started asynchronously.

Also I may have understood this tutorial in wrong way, I am new at boost::asio but it looks to me that this tutor doesn't depict what author wanted to demonstrate.

Author says:

> The single threaded approach is usually the best place to start when
>   developing applications using asio. The downside is the limitations it
>   places on programs, particularly servers, including:
>
> - Poor responsiveness when handlers can take a long time to complete.
> - An inability to scale on multiprocessor systems.

So when author tells about poor responsiveness it means that we could run multiple tasks (callbacks in this case) concurrently so that we engage all available cores.
But this approach works ideally when there are no shared data to modify.
However in this tutorial callbacks DO modify shared variable `count` and write to `cout`.
To avoid concurrent modification author places callbacks into `strand` object which guarantees that callbacks execute one after another in order they came into the "queue".

So callbacks are not something heavy and long-to-execute in this tutorial ...

**Question 2**: Do you think that using `strand` object is necessary in this tutorial?

I think this tutorial is overengineered, once again please correct me if I am wrong, but this code without additional thread and `strand` object seems to work the same way as original tutorial:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

class printer
{
public:
  printer(boost::asio::io_context& io)
    : timer1_(io, boost::asio::chrono::seconds(1)),
      timer2_(io, boost::asio::chrono::seconds(1)),
      count_(0)
  {
    timer1_.async_wait(boost::bind(&printer::print1, this));

    timer2_.async_wait(boost::bind(&printer::print2, this));
  }

  ~printer()
  {
    std::cout << "Final count is " << count_ << std::endl;
  }

  void print1()
  {
    if (count_ < 10)
    {
      std::cout << "Timer 1: " << count_ << std::endl;
      ++count_;

      timer1_.expires_at(timer1_.expiry() + boost::asio::chrono::seconds(1));
      timer1_.async_wait(boost::bind(&printer::print1, this));
    }
  }

  void print2()
  {
    if (count_ < 10)
    {
      std::cout << "Timer 2: " << count_ << std::endl;
      ++count_;

      timer2_.expires_at(timer2_.expiry() + boost::asio::chrono::seconds(1));
      timer2_.async_wait(boost::bind(&printer::print2, this));
    }
  }

private:
  boost::asio::steady_timer timer1_;
  boost::asio::steady_timer timer2_;
  int count_;
};

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_context io;
  printer p(io);
  io.run();

  return 0;
}
```

**Question 3**: Is the code above correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `run()` a from a second thread is the point of the tutorial.

Your two questions have the same answer. The Timer.5 tutorial shows you how to have more than 1 thread service the `io_context` (more than 1 thread calls `run()`). But running multithreaded means that you'd have to protect shared state from concurrent access and that is why the `strand` object is needed.

You are right that in this example you don't need the strand if you call `run()` from only one thread.

Comment: So if I understand it right second thread is needed to handle callback when `timer2_` times out? And if I want to add 3rd timer I would add `print3()` function similar to `print1()` and `print2()` and one more thread?

Comment: @VadimSorochan, no the number of print functions is unrelated to the number of threads and although each timer in the example is bound to different functions they could also just as easily both bind to the same `print1()` function. This code would also work with 2 threads, 10 timers bound to 10 print functions, or 20 threads, 15 timers all calling the same print() function. As soon as a timer expires, any available thread may be used to call the corresponding function and if all threads are busy handling other events, the associated function will be called whenever a thread returns.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Now I understand that if concurrent thread runs `io_context.run` the callback can be executed in any of two thread that run `io_context.run`.

Answer (score 0):

### Question 1

Its not needed for "successful" program execution, but the program was designed to be a scenario where you need `boost::asio::strand`s. Since you have only 1 thread again, you don't need them anymore, but the tutorial looses its purpose, as you had the same scenario as in the tutorial before:

> The previous four tutorials avoided the issue of handler
>   synchronisation by calling the io_context::run() function from one
>   thread only

### Question 2

Yes I do, not using them would be a data race which would invoke undefined behavior. So crashes or sometimes correct execution sometimes not, depending on the state of the universe. Since the only purpose of the tutorials code is to show the usage of strands, when you remove that intention, you could just write `int main() {}` and it would still "work".

### Question 3

Seems correct, but again, your code would just be solution for tutorial 4 not 5.

---

Imagine a video streaming server, you would have timers to send video RTP packets in a defined interval, but also handlers for processing RTSP, serving multiple clients. There would be a lot of work in those handlers, like calculating checksums, parsing text, and you certainly want to utilize the other 15 cores in your server. But would not want to corrupt the data of a session. So you use a strand for a session. So you can run multiple threads on your context. And if you don't simply want to imagine, [look here](https://github.com/superlokkus/rtsp).

Comment: thanks for your answer.
 But what happens when I run new thread `boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_context::run, &io));`?

Comment: Is running `boost::asio::io_context::run` in another thread intended to handle callbacks that come from this thread(via calling async_wait)?
Also do I understand correct: if I want to add `print3` to `printer` class, I also need to create one more thread that runs `io_context::run`?